# My monitor doesn't want to display Ubuntu. What's going on?

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 off a CD on a Dell PowerEdge 2650 server. The installation went fine. However, during the first boot up, right after post, my display goes black and my monitor displays the following error mesage:

```
The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change 
your input timing to 1680x1050@60Hz or any other monitor listing timing as per 
the monitor specifications.
```

Has anyone else had this experience? The monitor is also a Dell 19" display.